# Factorising a two-variable equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, factoring

I have an equation:

$-\frac{\cos(kL_1)}{\sin(kL_1)} + 2\frac{1-\cos(kL_2)}{\sin(kL_2)} =0 $

that I would like to factor to separate my variables as such:
$[f(kL_2)][f(kL_1)] =0$,
I've been trying for a while using various trig identities and exponential forms, but I can't quite manage to separate them. Can anyone provide any help or suggest a way I might be able to do it?

*Edit 1: I know the functions can be separated such that: $[f(kL_2)][f(kL_1)] =1$ , but I worry as to how that will impact my analysis of the functions.

Comment: So what have you done? Anything beyond clearing fractions and fiddling around?

Comment: @martycohen Thankyou for your comment. I fist tried to convert all the trig functions into their respective complex exponential forms, then gathered the equation into one shared fraction to then look for a shared factor to take out, this seemingly does not work.  I also tried using the trig identity: $1-\cos(x) = \sin^2(x/2)$ to see if that would help but I think my problem is finding a correct method in which to factor rather than a lack of knowledge of identities/complex forms.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I can do.

To make it easier,
let
$kL_1=a
$
and
$kL_2=b
$.
This becomes
$\frac{\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}
= 2\frac{1-\cos(b)}{\sin(b)}
$
or
$\cot(a)
=2(\csc(b)-\cot(b))
=2\tan(b/2)
$.

Comment: In the light of this answer, would it be okay to state that my solutions to the equation are the intersecting points of f(a) and f(b)? To elaborate on that, I mean that is the answer you gave mathematically equivalent to just looking at the roots of $f(a)f(b) = 0$. I think this is correct, so apologies if it seems like I'm stating the obvious.

Comment: My result shows that for any a you can solve for b and vice versa. This is in the form f(a)=g(b), not f(a)f(b)=0.